# Migration from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, migration

I have a planned migration from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. However, I don't know what the best idea out of the following two is:

- **Upgrade 20.04 to 22.04**: I 'm afraid of some function will don't work or there will be a lot of bugs to fix.
- **Format drive with 20.04 and install 22.04**: I don't know if it is possible to move all data from my backup 20.04 to 22.04 without problems and bugs and configure the new system to my needs. This may also take a lot of time.

What is your experience with migration? What should I pay attention to in order to do it right? Can my backed data from 20.04 with the Deja Dup utility be restored on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I personally faced only one issue - the firefox snap had some permission errors. Switching to the apt version fixed them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: `what you should pay attention to in order to do it right` -- You don't have to, Ubuntu devs performed a lot of tests to ensure that the upgrade process would be smooth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu releases undergo thorough testing, and it is unlikely that you would encounter a major bug.

---

### Test it out

You can download Ubuntu 22.04 ISO, and flash it on a USB drive, and test it in a live session.

If you don't find any issue with your day to day tasks, go ahead and either fresh install Ubuntu 22.04 with the flash drive, or perform an upgrade.

---

### If you don't want to upgrade

However, if this is a very critical machine and you cannot afford to live with a bug, you can simply not upgrade. Ubuntu 20.04 would be supported until 2025 (it is an LTS release - LTS stands for Long Term Support).

Comment: Thanks for advice, in summary, it is safer to update ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 or fresh installation and backup data from 20 to 22, is such a data backup from 20 using the deja dup tool can be restored on ubuntu 22?

Comment: You can just backup the data to another partition. If you want to be really safe about data, consider backing up in cloud/external drive. Both fresh installations and online upgrade are safe. Online upgrade might be more convenient for you.